# Issue with JSON Decoding? / How can I debug this?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, struct

I'm making an API call and managing the data received, but my call is catching an error. Here's my getData() code:

```
    func getData(from url: String) {
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print("something went wrong.")
        return
    }

    do {
        self.instructionsResults = try JSONDecoder().decode([Step].self, from: data)
        print("getData() was successful!")
        print(self.instructionsResults)
    } catch {
        print("Decoding error:")
        print(String(describing: error)) // <-- this pings
    }
}).resume()
}
```

Here's a pastebin of an example url json data: [link](https://pastebin.com/9epD3n2a)

And here's the struct I've defined for this fetch:

```
struct Step: Codable {        
  let number: Int
  let step: String?
}
```

This may be extra, but I'm using the call above to populate the array instantiated as `var steps: [String] = []` with the step: String data of each step in the JSON Step array.

```
for n: Int in 0 ..< instructionsResults.count {
        if instructionsResults[n].step != nil {
            let step = instructionsResults[n].step ?? "n/a"
            print("step: \(instructionsResults[n].step)")
            print("step: \(step)")
            steps.append(step)
        }
    }
    print("Steps: \(steps)")
}
```

Does anyone have any insight on what's going wrong? My final print statement always returns as empty. I've done a similar type of call formatted a similar way earlier in this project, and that worked completely fine, so I'm stumped as to where I went wrong with this one. Any insight / feedback would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

**Edit**: Here's the error code:

```
Steps: []
Decoding error:
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "number", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"number\", intValue: nil) (\"number\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that there is no key `number` in the top level object.

Please read the JSON carefully. You are ignoring the object on the root level, the array with the key `steps`.

You need this

```
struct Root: Decodable { 
    let steps: [Step]
}

struct Step: Decodable {        
    let number: Int
    let step : String
}
```

and decode

```
.decode([Root].self,
```

Comment: Hi, that makes sense. How can I go about accessing the content of each Step in steps, then? / do you know of a resource I can find that for myself from? Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: The two structs represent actually the entire rules of decoding JSON. `{` becomes a struct, `[{` becomes an array of a struct, everything in double quotes is `String`, `true/false` (not in double quotes) is `Bool`, floating point numbers (not in double quotes) are `Double`, integers `Int`. That's it

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. I think I've figured it out..